# Using Python's multiprocessing module together with the cvxopt package

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, cvxopt

I just came across an issue with the [cvxopt package](http://cvxopt.org/) for convex optimization, which I didn't find mentioned in the [documentation](http://cvxopt.org/documentation/index.html#). I wonder if anybody knows what causes it and how to best work around it.

The issue is that when you `import cvxopt` in a Python program that makes use of [`multiprocessing.Process`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) instances, the processes can no longer run in parallel. They seem to get automatically synchronized. Note that this happens regardless of whether any of the `cvxopt` functions are actually used by the program. Simply importing the package causes this effect.

**Example:**

```
# import cvxopt
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def compute(queue):
    """
    Pick integers from a queue and perform some useless
    calculations on them just to keep the CPU busy.
    """
    total = 0
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        for i in range(item):
            total += i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    procs = []
    for i in range(4):
        proc = Process(target = compute,
                       args   = (queue,))
        proc.start()
        procs.append(proc)

    for i in range(100000):
        queue.put(i)
    for proc in procs:
        queue.put(None)
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

The script above starts four processes running in parallel to the main program. On a machine with four cores I got four processes, each taking 100% of a CPU.

However, when uncommenting the `import cvxopt` statement at the start, each process ends up taking only 25% of a CPU, as if it was synchronized with the others.

I am interested in both explanations and work-arounds. I apologize if there is an obvious explanation in the documentation that I overlooked.

---

**Details on how to reproduce the problem**

The environment I am running this under is Linux 3.5.0 (Ubuntu 12.10 distribution), and Python 3.2.3. This is how I installed cvxopt:

1. Install matplotlib 1.2.1 (I did this because it includes pylab, which is used in many of the cvxopt example scripts. I am unsure if this is an actual requirement). I used [this tar.gz package](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.2.1/matplotlib-1.2.1.tar.gz) and did `sudo python3 setup.py install` to install it.
2. Installed BLAS and ATLAS

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libblas-dev libblas3 libatlas-base-dev libatlas3-base libblas-test libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev
   ```

   The above is probably more than necessary, but I'd be surprised if that caused any problems.
3. Installed cvxopt 1.1.6, using the tar.gz package [from here](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/download/) and `sudo python3 ./setup.py install`.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention your OS, and whether you are using any of the optional dependencies listed in https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: @JanneKarila Thanks again for the note. I've added more details to the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something to do with the Python GIL not released ?

See : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.user/15678

Comment: It may have something to do with this, but I'd like to understand this better. As far as I know the `multiprocessing` module (as opposed to the `threading` module) shouldn't directly be affected by the GIL.